# Why do these two code fragments differ

Tags: java

I just noticed that when I change the last line in the code fragment from `potential =+ rep_pot`  to `potential = potential + rep_pot`, I get completely different behaviour. Has anybody got any idea why this is happening?

```
double potential = euclideanDistance(i, goal);
for (IntPoint h: hits){
    double dist = euclideanDistance(i, h);
    double a = range - dist;
    double rep_pot = (Math.exp(-1/a)) / dist;
    potential =+ rep_pot;
}
```

Comment: what are two different behavior you are seeing?

Comment: what is =+ ? did you mean += ?

Comment: and it should be `+=`, instead of `=+` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because these two things are not equivalent.

```
potential =+ rep_pot;
```

Here we have potential assigned a value of the expression 'unary plus rep_pot'

The thing you intendet to write looks differently:

```
potential += rep_pot;
```

And this is equivalent to

```
potential = potential + rep_pot;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `=+` operator in Java. See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) for all legal operators.

`=+` are *two* operators: `=` followed by `+`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
potential = potential + rep_pot
```

is similar to

```
potential += rep_pot
```

and

```
potential =+ rep_pot;
```

is the same as

```
potential = rep_pot;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant `+=`. In your case it is interpreted as `x = +x` which is `x = x`

Use `+=` :

```
potential += rep_pot;
```